# OpenGL 3.3+ - Shaders, attributes, uniforms, in/out variables - How, what, when, why?

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, rendering, game-engine

I am currently learning OpenGL 3.3+ and the modern, shader based rendering process. So far, I've been able to create my own binding for GLFW and OpenGL using C# and I've got a fairly good understanding of how everything works now. I like doing everything from scratch because I love knowing how everything in my project works.

But something that just doesn't want to "stick" is: What exactly is the difference between in/out-variables, attributes and uniforms. How do I know which one to use? I would like to think that I've got a fairly good understanding of how the OpenGL State-Machine works, but this part of the rendering process is rarely explained in detail. Most tutorials or books just say "this is how you pass data to the shaders" but I've yet to find a text explaining which method to use and most importantly: why.

Also, I would love some more info on the connection between shaders and VBOs. I guess that can be combined with my question above.

**Another edit to make the question more specific**: Is there a source explaining the relationship between varyings, attributes, uniforms and buffer objects in detail? How do they work? Which one to use when? What should be avoided?

Comment: This is a great question, especially with the edit. Attrib/Varying/Uniform and their relationship to bindables is a source of endless mistakes for newcomers to GL. Beaver has provided a quality answer that could help such newcomers. I imagine it's probably against a rule to defend the importance of a question, but... :S

Comment: @JoshParnell Thanks for your reply Josh. I hope you don't mind that I used your comment to re-word my question to be a little more specific. Maybe we can get some more answers in this thread this way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences between the variables of shaders are as follows:

Attributes are per vertex data fragments. The purpose of these variables is to provide additional data to the position of a vertex. Texture coordinates, normals and colors which are specific to each vertex are good examples for attributes. In the most common case you provide attributes to a shader by creating vertex buffer objects and attach this data to an attribute in the shader.

Uniforms contains values that does not change during a single rendering call. That's why matrices are often seen put into a uniform value since the transformation for a mesh is the same for all its vertices.

Varyings are used to pass information between shaders. These values does only exist on the GPU. Values of varyings are interpolated accross the entire polygon. You provide just the values for 3 vertices but the fragments will contain the interpolated values based on 3 vertex values.

Connecting vertex buffers to your shader is done by binding your vertex buffer and provide information on the attibute pointers into vertex buffers.

I would recommend to get a recent edition of the "red book" which is a quite comprehensive learing ressource for OpenGL. It would also stick to an exact version of OpenGL's core profile. Compatibility mode is a nightmare to start with since all legacy functions are allowed to be used and there are many tutorials on the web which mix features of different OpenGL versions. Don't do that... You will regret.
Grab a reference card for this exact version (e.g. https://www.khronos.org/files/opengl4-quick-reference-card.pdf) an focus on the features of one version.